# What is the closure of this set?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, sequences-and-series

$\{a_n\}_{n=1}^{n=\infty}$ is a bounded sequence in $\mathbb{C}$

Is ${\overline{\{a_n\}}}=\{a_n\}$ ?

Comment: Only if $\overline{\{a_n\}}$ is finite.

Answer (score 1):

No: the closure of $\{a_n,n\in\mathbb N\}$ can be any non-empty closed set $F$. Indeed, this set is separable for the induced topology, hence we take a countable dense subset for the induced topology. This will be dense in $F$ for the usual topology.

Comment: How do you prove it's separable for the induced topology?

Comment: A subset of a separable metric space is separable for the induced metric.

Comment: Yes, but I don't understand why. Can you give me a hint?

Comment: Here is an argument, maybe it can be simplified in the case of real line. A metric space is separable if and only if there is a countable basis of open sets. (it's the key point of the proof)

Comment: If separable, then because metric spaces are first-countable, $|\omega\times\omega|=|\omega|$ implies second countable. If second countable, then take one point from each element of a countable base. Any non-empty open set must include an element of said base, thus one of the chosen points. So I guess it works for all first-countable spaces given countable choice. The rest of the proof is just that a subspace of a second-countable space is obviously second-countable. I must have known this a year or two ago! Without countable choice, this proof falls apart.

Comment: Without countable choice, it seems almost certain that there could be a subspace of a separable metric space that is not separable, but I don't know nearly enough set theory to prove it.